# How can i calculate the number of the rows that have same names in table? SQL

Tags: sql

I want to calculate how many rows have each name. For example I have 2 table: `adt_agentia_principala` and `adt_filiale_agentie` they are connected with a foreign key.

Now, I have `nume_agentie` for `adt_agentia_principala` and `id_filiala` for `adt_filiale_agentie` when I run the following statement :

```
SELECT 
    adt_filiala_agentie.id_filiala, adt_agentia_principala.nume_agentie 
FROM 
    adt_filiala_agentie 
LEFT JOIN 
    adt_agentia_principala ON adt_filiala_agentie.id_agentie = adt_agentia_principala.id_agentie;
```

My output is:

[image]

I want to calculate how many `id_filiala` is there when joined with `nume_agentie`. This is what I've tried so far but doesn't work.

Expected output:

```
|=====================|==========|
|  MOLDOVA TUR S.R.L  |    16    |  
|=====================|==========|    
| BASARABIA TUR S.R.L |    10    |  
|=====================|==========|     
|   Panda Tur S.R.L   |    1     |  
|=====================|==========|
```

`MOLDOVA TUR S.R.L` have `16 id's` , `BASARABIA TUR S.R.L 10 id's` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this query to achieve your expected output:

```sql
SELECT ap.nume_agentie, COUNT(*)
FROM adt_filiala_agentie fa
LEFT JOIN adt_agentia_principala ap
ON fa.id_agentie = ap.id_agentie
GROUP BY ap.nume_agentie
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `group by`:

```
SELECT fa.id_filiala, COUNT(*)
FROM adt_filiala_agentie fs LEFT JOIN
     adt_agentia_principala ap
     ON fa.id_agentie = ap.id_agentie
GROUP BY fa.id_filiala;
```

Note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll notice that, but it didn't helped me. I need to output the "name" and on the following column the "number of rows".  Like in the exapmle up there:
 name |  n rows

Comment: @CucuIonut-Nicu . . . This puts the name and count in the same row.

Comment: i tested it in phpMyAdmin, it didn't work, maybe the problem is there, anyway, thank you very much for the attention paid to me <3

Comment: @CucuIonut-Nicu . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle illustrating the issue?